# How to fix ''could not find Image for "kope.io/k8s..." when running kops update cluster ${NAME} --yes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, kops, aws-fargate

I am setting up a kubernetes cluster on AWS. I run the following commands to create the cluster and fails when the final command is run, `kops update cluster`

## COMMANDS

```
vim ~/.aws/config
```

Add the the following text

```
[default]
region = eu-west-2
```

```
kops delete cluster --name ${CLUSTER_NAME} --yes

export CLUSTER_NAME=example-1-kops1.k8s.local
export REGION=eu-west-2
export AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONES=eu-west-2b
export KUBERNETES_VERSION=v1.14.1
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://example-1-com-state-store
export KOPS_STATE_STORE_S3=example-1-com-state-store

aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region $REGION

aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $KOPS_STATE_STORE_S3 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=$REGION

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket $KOPS_STATE_STORE_S3 --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled

kops create cluster --name=$CLUSTER_NAME \
  --state=$KOPS_STATE_STORE --zones=$AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONES \
  --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro \
--ssh-public-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa-example-1.pub

kops update cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} --yes
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
error running task "LaunchConfiguration/nodes.example-1-kops1.k8s.local" (9m57s remaining to succeed): could not find Image for "kope.io/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13"
W0514 01:23:03.908405   21889 executor.go:130] error running task "LaunchConfiguration/master-eu-west-2b.masters.example-1-kops1.k8s.local" (9m57s remaining to succeed): could not find Image for "kope.io/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13"
```

Comment: Hi, Looks like that is an old bug; https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/3282 . Can you refer https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/images.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome on StackOverflow. It looks like intermittent issue with image repository of owner 383156758163 (alias kope.io). 
Simply 'kope.io/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13' image did not exist in any AWS region, in the time you were creating KOPS cluster. I  verified it with:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner 383156758163 --filters 'Name=name,Values=k8s-*-debian-stretch*' | grep k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64
```

**Update**:

Image is showing up right now in describe-images's output:

```
"ImageLocation": "383156758163/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13",
            "Name": "k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13",
            "ImageLocation": "383156758163/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-14",
            "Name": "k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-14",
```

Check out Image's CreationDate: "2019-05-14T08:57:47.000Z"

Please give it try again, should work now.

Comment: Thanks @Nepomucen! I am able to create the cluster on AWS now